# how to get the column value from Stored Procedure using invoke method in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have used getMethod.Invoke method to execute the stored procedure in ASP.NET MVC 5. The method "GetStoredProcedure" is able to execute the stored procedure, but not able to get the exact return value (ID & its name) from stored procedure. 
I got the following results from EF instead of list value (ID & its name)"{System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult`1[EF.Data.SaveTEST1_Result]}    System.Linq.IQueryable {System.Linq.EnumerableQuery}".

Please help me how to get return value from stored procedure using invoke method in EF ASP.NET MVC 5.

I have pasted the code sample, which I have used

```
public object GetStoredProcedure(string storedProcedure, object[] parameters)
{
        Type contextType = context.GetType();
        MethodInfo getMethod = contextType.GetMethod(storedProcedure);
        var result = getMethod.Invoke(context, parameters);
        return result;
}
```

and also the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SaveTEST1  
     (@id INT, @name VARCHAR(5))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MaxID INT

    SELECT @MaxID = MAX(ID) 
    FROM TEST1

    INSERT INTO TEST1 
    VALUES(@MaxID, @name)

    SELECT ID, Name 
    FROM TEST1 
    WHERE ID = @MaxID
END
```

Note: I'm using repository pattern and reflection class.
I hope that above explanation is enough, to explain me the how to get my expected result.

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with asp.net-mvc

Comment: Please check your procedure is returning data or not

Comment: Gulshan, Yes it returns the value in SQL query window.

Comment: It would greatly clarify the question if you could provide a snippet of code that works and does not use Reflection but accesses EF in the usual way.

Comment: John, if I use EF in usual way then the repository class will not be used and my pattern is to use repository class. Kindly help me, how to get my expected result in it.